# scraping table from site - finding blank cells, python

Tags: python

Here's the site I'm working with: http://www.fantasypros.com/mlb/probable-pitchers.php

What I want to do it run the code every day, and it return a list of pitchers that are pitching that day, so just the first column. Here's what I have so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.fantasypros.com/mlb/probable-pitchers.php'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table',{'class': 'table table-condensed'})
table2 = table.find('tbody') #this find just the rows with pitchers (excludes dates)

daysOnPage = []

for row in table.findAll('th'):
    daysOnPage.append(row.text)

daysOnPage.pop(0)
#print(daysOnPage)

pitchers = []
for row in table2.findAll('a', {'class': 'available mpb-available'}):
    pitchers.append(row.text)
```

This returns a list of every pitcher on the page. If every cell on the table was always filled, I could do something like deleting every nth player or something like that, but that seems pretty inelegant, and also doesn't work since you don't ever know which cells will be blank. I've looked through the table2.prettify() code but I can't find anything that indicates to me where a blank cell is coming.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Tinkering a little bit, I've figured this much out:

```
for row in table2.find('tr'):
    for a in row.findAll('a', {'class': 'available mpb-available'}):
        pitchers.append(a.text)
continue
```

That prints the first row of pitchers, which is also a problem I was going to tackle later. Why does the `continue` not make it iterate through the rows?

Answer (score 1):

When I hear table, I think pandas. You can have `pandas.read_html` do the parsing for you then use  `pandas.Series.dropna` return only valid values.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: dfs = pd.read_html('http://www.fantasypros.com/mlb/probable-pitchers.php')

In [3]: df = dfs[0].head(10)  # get the first dataframe and just use the first 10 teams for this example

In [4]: print(df['Thu Aug 6'])  # Selecting just one day by label
0    @WSHJ. Hellickson(7-6)SP 124
1         MIAM. Wisler(5-1)SP 306
2                             NaN
3     @NYYE. Rodriguez(6-3)SP 177
4        SFK. Hendricks(4-5)SP 51
5       STLM. Lorenzen(3-6)SP 300
6                             NaN
7                             NaN
8                             NaN
9          KCB. Farmer(0-2)SP 270
Name: Thu Aug 6, dtype: object

In [5]: active = df['Thu Aug 6'].dropna()  # now just drop any fields that are NaNs

In [6]: print(active)
0    @WSHJ. Hellickson(7-6)SP 124
1         MIAM. Wisler(5-1)SP 306
3     @NYYE. Rodriguez(6-3)SP 177
4        SFK. Hendricks(4-5)SP 51
5       STLM. Lorenzen(3-6)SP 300
9          KCB. Farmer(0-2)SP 270
Name: Thu Aug 6, dtype: object
```

I suppose the last thing you'll want to do is parse the strings in the table to get just the pitchers name.

If you want to write the Series to a csv, you can do so directly by:

```
    In [7]: active.to_csv('active.csv')
```

This gives you a csv that looks something like this:

```
0,@WSHJ. Hellickson(7-6)SP 126
1,MIAM. Wisler(5-1)SP 306
3,@NYYE. Rodriguez(6-3)SP 179
4,SFK. Hendricks(4-5)SP 51
5,STLM. Lorenzen(3-6)SP 301
9,KCB. Farmer(0-2)SP 267
```

Comment: I've peripherally seen some stuff about pandas while working on this project (first thing I've done in python) but I never actually knew or looked into what it was. Maybe I should look into it now. Thanks.

Comment: Any idea how to write the resulting list from the read_html to a csv? I try to use the `to_csv` in pandas but I get an error, "'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'"

Comment: `read_html` returns a list of dataframes.  Hence my `[0]` in the example above.  You probably need to select a single dataframe from the list `dfs[0].to_csv(...)`

Comment: I did manage to get it into a csv by converting it to a numpy array. I'm still not clear on what your [0] in your example is for though. What does it do? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I added an example of how to write to a csv.  In my previous comment and in the read_html documentation, you'll see that read_html returns a `list` of dataframes, one for each table in the html file you provide.  The `[0]` simply returns the first table in that list.